# jQuery - Nest Dialogs 3 levels

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am trying to nest 3 dialog boxes. What I am trying to do is provide a button to the user that he can click. Once he clicks, he would see a confirmation popup to proceed with the action. He can either click "Cancel" to resume the normal browsing of the website or click "Yes, confirm" to launch another dialog box that will show him some details and 2 buttons namely "Print" & "Cancel". If user clicks Print, it should launch the print preview and print some info from database. If he clicks "Cancel", another popup should ask him if he really wants to cancel printing. If he clicks "Yes, Cancel printing" button, it should close the 3rd and 2nd popups, thus taking him back to the first popup. How can I achieve this functionality.

I referred to the following post on SO as it has infinite dialog popups, but I want to limit the pop-ups to 2-3 levels:

[Jquery UI modal dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637327/jquery-ui-modal-dialogs)

How can I achieve the requested functionality, in terms of coding (as I am novice to JS coding)?

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example showing you how to invoke a new dialog from another dialog. You'll have to tailor it to your needs. You can try the working code here:  http://jsbin.com/oyosiv

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b1">Open Dialogbox</button>

<div id="d1" title="Dialog Box One" style="display: none">
    One!
</div>
<div id="d2" title="Dialog Box Two" style="display: none">
    Two!
</div>
<div id="d3" title="Dialog Box Three" style="display: none">
    Three!
</div>
</body>

<script>
$("#d1").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 
      "Open Two": function() { $("#d2").dialog("open"); },
      "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
    }
});

$("#d2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 
      "Open Three": function() { $("#d3").dialog("open"); },
      "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
    }
});

$("#d3").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 
      "Okay": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
    }
});

$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#d1").dialog("open");
});

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: AWESOME!!! Works for me! I really appreciate it. Accepted & Up'pd. Thank youuuuuuuu...